# Whats wrong with my regular expression?

Tags: regex, linux, terminal, grep

Here's what I got:

```
grep -E '^([0-9]+[0-9]*[.]+[:blank:]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)' text.txt
```

I am trying to find all matches that have one or more digits followed by a "." dot, atlas one space and followed by at least one character or number, at the beginning. So, some possible matches would be,

```
1. hello
2. this works too
5. Fantastic show
12. Target
```

What's wrong with what I got.

Comment: This site might help you with your regex https://regexr.com/

Comment: @ctwheels, not (portably) with `grep` you can't. What you're providing above has PCRE syntax not guaranteed to be present in ERE without platform-specific extensions. The ERE specification doesn't include `\d`, *or* `\s`, *or* `\w`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for pointing that out. I'll delete my previous comment so as to not cause further confusion for non-PCRE syntax users. The regex still could be simplified, however, since the first token is greedy, thus the second token really is redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't include spaces in the post-number match expression:

`[a-zA-Z0-9]+`.

You can also simplify your expression.

- `[0-9]+[0-9]*` should just be `[0-9]+`, or more simply `\d+`. Your original expression means "match one or more digits and then zero or more digits". One or more already handles your expected input.
- `[.]+` - Do you expect more than a single period? If not, you only want `[.]`

Given that, I'd change your expression to:

```
^([0-9]+[.][[:blank:]]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)
```

(edits to the posix `[[:blank:]]` thanks to @randomir).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding validity, two things:

- `[:blank:]` is a character class. To use it in a range you have to wrap it with `[ ]`, like so: `[[:blank:]]`
- your last range expression does not include spaces, so you match only the first word

Fixed, looks like:

```
$ grep -E '^([0-9]+[0-9]*[.]+[[:blank:]]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)' text.txt
1. hello
2. this works too
5. Fantastic show
12. Target
```

Otherwise, as others have hinted, your expression can be simplified. If you need to stick to POSIX extended regular expressions ([ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html)), note that `[0-9]+[0-9]*` is equivalent to `[0-9]+`.

If you can enable the PCRE support (with `-P`, available only in GNU `grep`, regarded as *experimental* feature), you can simplify the character ranges used. For example you can use `\d` instead of POSIX `[[:digit:]]` (or `[0-9]`), and `\w` instead of `[[:alnum:]]` (or `[a-zA-Z0-9]`):

```
$ grep -P '^\d+\.+\s+[\w ]+' text.txt
```

Comment: Only if you use PCRE. Also, maybe OP wants multiple dots matched, he didn't specify.

Comment: Looking at the context of the input and the remark `followed by a "." dot`, I believe it's a single dot, but the OP may be able to better clarify. Regardless of it being PCRE or not, you can simplify `[0-9]+[0-9]*` to `[0-9]+` at least. The second really is redundant and will never get matched since the first token is greedy.

Comment: You're right about that part, `[0-9]+[0-9]*` is equivalent to `[0-9]+`.

Comment: Yes I meant to say its only suppose to match one dot. Sorry about that.

Comment: @IanHoyos, alright, then just omit the `+` operator after the dot, and the dot will be matched verbatim (if, of course, properly escaped).